# jQuery and Colorbox "Is Not A Function"

Tags: jquery, html, css, colorbox

I've been working on integrating Colorbox (a lightbox alternative) into a site.

Ok, so my head file is:

```
<head>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" href="../colorbox/colorbox.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="../colorbox/jquery.colorbox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function saveToBook() { 
        $.fn.colorbox({inline:false, href:'../index.html'}); 
    };
</script>
</head>
```

My Link is as follows:

```
<a href="#save-to-book" onclick="javascript:parent.saveToBook();return false;" class="recipe-links">Save to Cookbook</a>
```

The only output I recieve (from FireBug) is:

```
$.fn.colorbox is not a function
```

Comment: Are you positive the jquery.colorbox.js is getting loaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey, sorry for wasting peoples time - I had been running this on my local machine.

I just decided to upload it to a beta server and it all functions fine, obviously didn't like my path names :)

Thanks @NickCraver for giving it a shot, and cheers @PetersenDidlt

Answer (score 7):

My best guess would be that `../colorbox/jquery.colorbox.js` is not the correct path, are you sure it's not something like this?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/colorbox/jquery.colorbox.js"></script>
```

Also, your script should be more like this:

```
$(function() {
  $("a[href='#save-to-book']").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().colorbox({inline:false, href:'../index.html'});
    return false;
  });
});
```

And just remove your current function and the `onclick` from the anchor itself.

Comment: Just for the record, not sure who has been voting this up but the client wanted a standard JavaScript function not jQuery and jquery.colorbox.js is being added properly - sorted now anyway, thought I would just put this here.

Comment: @Neurofluxation - Actually the problem **was** that it was *not* being added properly, since posting it on a different server worked, the file, path or permissions, whatever the issue, it was not being included in the page.

Answer (score -1):

Hey see below this is your code where you close script 2

`<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script></script>`

Comment: Yeah, doesn't matter - I fixed it ages ago now... May 18th 2010... :/